# select() system call will not unblock

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am stuck getting the select() system call to unblock.  I am trying to multiplex data input from a set of 3 sockets.  I create a socket for each interface in an array of ints called sock[]. If I uncomment the first block, I am able to receive data on each socket without issue.  With the comments it, I never get past the call to select().  Can you see anything I may be doing wrong regarding the select() setup and call?

```
//This block will receive data from sock[0], sock[1], and sock[2] when left uncommented
   /*n = recvfrom(sock[2], buf, 1500,0,(struct sockaddr*)&recvaddr, &recvaddrlen);
    printf("\nrecieved\n");
    print_buf(buf);*/

    fd_set sockets;
    FD_ZERO(&sockets);
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        FD_SET(sock[i], &sockets);
    }


    select(3, &sockets, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    printf("\nSocket selected\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        //Check for connected sockets
        if(FD_ISSET(i, &sockets)){
            printf("\nSocket %d", i);
            n = recvfrom(sock[i], buf, 1500,0,(struct sockaddr*)&recvaddr, &recvaddrlen);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I strongly suggest switching to `poll` instead of `select`. It really is a terrible function to use.

Comment: @SergeyA - unfortunately, I think `select` is still the most portable, so in  some circumstances its use may be justified.  That said, `poll` is my go to for simple usage.  `epoll` is more powerful, but harder to use and Linux-only.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland, I am not aware of any modern system which has `select`, but not `poll`. Do you have a specific example? `epoll` is, of course, Linux specific.

Comment: The only thing that immediately comes to mind are light-weight / alternate TCP/IP stacks, e.g. lwIP and similar commercial solutions.   Though with a little googling, it sounds like all the major OS's have supported it as of ~10 years ago (Win Vista & OSX 10.4) , which means very few (if any?) systems running a still-supported OS version will have the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing the wrong value for the nfds parameter.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

"nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1. "

What you want is something like

```
int maxsock =0;
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    FD_SET(sock[i], &sockets);
    if (sock[i] > maxsock) maxsock = sock[i]
}


select(maxsock+1, &sockets, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```